# Jasmine - AngularJS $https inside a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, angularjs-service

I am newbie in Jasmine. I have angular service like below,

```
app.factory('helper', ['$http', function($http){ 
        var helper = {};

        helper.http = function(setting){
            if(typeof setting !== 'object'){
                console.log('Error: Please provide a valid setting for the http request!');
                return false;
            }

            if(!setting.url){
                console.log('Error: Please provide a request url for the http request!');
                return false;
            }

            var url = setting.url,
            method = setting.method || 'GET';
            data = setting.data || '';
            headers = setting.headers || '';
            console.log('coming');
            $http({
                method: method,
                url: url,
                data: data,
                headers: headers
            })
            .success(function(response){
                setting.success(response);
            })
            .error(function(error){
                console.log('Angular $http Error:' + error);
            });
        };

        return helper; 
    }
]);
```

I am trying to write the test case for the above service. Test case will look like,

```
describe('app module: ', function(){
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    describe('service "helper"', function(){
        it('should return false when invalid setting is passed', inject(function(helper){
            expect(helper.http()).toBeFalsy();
        }));

        it('should return false when invalid url is passed in setting', inject(function(helper){
            expect(helper.http({
                method: 'GET'
            })).toBeFalsy();
        }));

        it('should return false when invalid url is', function(done){
            inject(function(helper){
                helper.http({
                    url: 'http://localhost:3000/get_users/560076',
                    method: 'GET',
                    success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        done();
                    }
                });
            })
        });
    });
});
```

The first two case works fine, but the third case doesn't consoles the response.

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. Is this a proper way to write a test case?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are expecting. The test description seems to suggest you expect helper.http(...) to return false - but that's only going to happen if you don't pass a url in the object. If you want to test the call, inject $httpBackend into your test and set it to expect a call.

Comment: What value is your `helper` giving?  You are just getting rid of promises (which are a great feature of `$http`).

Comment: Let me clear it. Yup, it return false when we do not pass a valid setting or url. But when we pass all valid data, it will return a list of objects on success. I am trying to console the response, so  I can try like `expect(response.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)`. The problem is it doesn't goes through the success callback.

Comment: In testing, $httpBackend won't do any real request, so the request to `localhost:3000/...` will never be made. You need to create some expectation in `$httpBackend`